# global-set-key performance in Emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, ide

I opened a very large file by emacs, and I found it is too slow to go to the top of the buffer by hit `M-<`. And I also found that it is normal when I enter the command `goto-line 1`. So I want to override the default keybinding like:

```
(defun hao-goto-beginning-of-buffer-quickly ()
  "Go to beginning of the buffer quickly"
  (interactive)
  (goto-line 1)
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<") 'hao-goto-beginning-of-buffer-quickly)
```

Then a weird situation happened. It is still very very slow when I hit `M-<`. But it is normal when I directly hit `M-x hao-goto-beginning-of-buffer-quickly`. I can not explain how this come? Do you ever come to this problem?

Comment: The global keymap *is* the lowest-priority keymap, so Emacs has to eliminate the other options first, but that's normally an entirely negligible delay. I suggest you use the in-built cpu profiler to work out what is responsible for that delay.

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions on [the Emacs site](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28197/global-set-key-performance-in-emacs) and this site at the same time.  Please pick one site or the other.